# Why is `gevent.spawn` different than a monkeypatched `threading.Thread()`?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent

While double checking that `threading.Condition` is correctly monkey patched, I noticed that a monkeypatched `threading.Thread(…).start()` behaves differently from `gevent.spawn(…)`.

Consider:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from threading import Thread, Condition
import gevent

cv = Condition()

def wait_on_cv(x):
    cv.acquire()
    cv.wait()
    print "Here:", x
    cv.release()

# XXX: This code yields "This operation would block forever" when joining the first thread
threads = [ gevent.spawn(wait_on_cv, x) for x in range(10) ]

"""
# XXX: This code, which seems semantically similar, works correctly
threads = [ Thread(target=wait_on_cv, args=(x, )) for x in range(10) ]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
"""

cv.acquire()
cv.notify_all()
print "Notified!"
cv.release()

for x, thread in enumerate(threads):
    print "Joining", x
    thread.join()
```

Note, specifically, the two comments starting with `XXX`.

When using the first line (with `gevent.spawn`), the first `thread.join()` raises an exception:

```
Notified!
Joining 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 30, in 
    thread.join()
  File "…/gevent/greenlet.py", line 291, in join
    result = self.parent.switch()
  File "…/gevent/hub.py", line 381, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

However, `Thread(…).start()` (the second block), everything works as expected.

Why would this be? What's the difference between `gevent.spawn()` and `Thread(…).start()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happen in your code is that the **greenlets** that you have created in you `threads` list didn't have yet the chance to be executed because `gevent` will not trigger a context switch until you do so explicitly in your code using `gevent.sleep()` and such or implicitly by calling a function that block e.g. `semaphore.wait()` or by yielding and so on ..., to see that you can insert a print before `cv.wait()` and see that it's called only after `cv.notify_all()` is called:

```
def wait_on_cv(x):
    cv.acquire()
    print 'acquired ', x
    cv.wait()
    ....
```

So an easy fix to your code will be to insert something that will trigger a context switch after you create your list of **greenlets**, example:

```
...
threads = [ gevent.spawn(wait_on_cv, x) for x in range(10) ]
gevent.sleep()  # Trigger a context switch
...
```

**Note:** I am still new to `gevent` so i don't know if this is the right way to do it :)

This way all the **greenlets** will have the chance to be executed and each one of them will trigger a context switch when they call `cv.wait()` and in the mean time they will
register them self to the condition waiters so that when `cv.notify_all()` is called it
will notify all the **greenlets**.

HTH,